# How to send HTML response in Hangouts Integration from Dialogflow

Tags: html, iframe, dialogflow-es, payload, google-hangouts

I am integrating dialogflow with google hangouts. I need to send a html iframe as a response to hangouts from dialogflow. I have used multiple ways like images, cards, custom payload but nothing worked. Can anyone tell me how can we give html iframe tag in google hangouts responses from Dialogflow.

Thanks in advance.